# How to hide all elements after a user response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know if i'm doing this right , sorry i'm new here. But the problem is that when i click the 3rd answer, nothing disapears, when i click the second answer, only the 3rd answer disappears, but  i want everything to disapear exactly how it happens when i click first answer

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.answers p').click(function()
        {
            var response = $(this).parent().data("specific");
                $(this).append(response);
            $(this).siblings().remove();
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

```
<div class="question">
    <div class="question-text">
    <p>First question?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="answers" data-specific=" First Response">
    <p>First answer</p>
    <div class="answers" data-specific=" Second Response">
    <p>Second answer</p>
    <div class="answers" data-specific=" Third Response">
    <p>Third answer</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What is your requirement exactly? From the question it is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Fix your divs; they're nested incorrectly.

Comment: what you mean with disappears ??  remove it or just hide it?

Comment: That is because you have a next `div` structure for answers, `siblings()` wont work here

Comment: I want to remove everything when i press an answer, but for 2nd and 3rd answer doesn't work, also divs fixed doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML need to change as you are having answer divs in nested form but it should be at same level (as far as I understand) and then put your logic of hiding in the jQuery as showm

```
<div class="question">
    <div class="question-text">
      <p>First question?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="answers" data-specific=" First Response">
      <p>First answer</p>
    </div><!--close your div here-->
    <div class="answers" data-specific=" Second Response">
      <p>Second answer</p>
    </div><!--close your div here-->
    <div class="answers" data-specific=" Third Response">
      <p>Third answer</p>
    </div><!--close your div here-->
</div>
```

and jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.answers p').click(function()
            {
                var $parent = $(this).parent(); 
                var response = $parent.data("specific");
                $(this).append(response);
                //hide all div with class=answers
                $parent.siblings('.answers').remove();
            });
      });
   </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it works. One more question though : If I want to make it recursive ( when I click first answer there will be again 3 ways to choose instead of first respone and so on  ) should i modify the divs ?

Comment: Yeah you can do it, just need to add same `<div class="answers"..` structure inside first div and same script will do

Comment: I tried that, and still doesn't work , sorry for asking you so much, but do you mind telling me what I did wrong in this code :                              http://jsbin.com/teximuhaba/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsbin.com/yadisitevi/1/) what you wanted?

So I added

```
$(this).parent().parent().children().each(function(){
  if(!($(this).hasClass('question-text') || $(this).data('specific') === response))
    $(this).remove();
});
```

And modified the HTML so that they are properly structured.

**EDIT**

Bhushan Kawadkar's answer is simpler, use that instead.